# Counting non-zero Gramians of Grassmanians over finite field

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields, grassmannians, q-analogs

In case of $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, we can obtain the number of all reduced row echelon forms (so called Grassmannians) for some m$\times$n full rank matrices by the following gaussian polynomial,
$$
\binom{n}{m}_{2} = \frac{(2^{n}-1)\cdots(2^{n-m+1}-1)}{(2^{m}-1)\cdots(2-1)}.
$$

Then I want to know the number of such matrices X satisfying that $\det(X*X^t)=1$ (so called Gramian).

E.g., for $2\times3$ matrix, the number of all reduced row echelon forms is
$$
\binom{3}{2}_{2} = 7
$$
and there are 4 matrices satisfying that $\det(X*X^t)=1$ in them s.t.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

When we denote such number $f(m,n)$, I obtain the following numbers:
$$
f(1,3)=f(2,3)=4=2^2 \quad \text{(upper case)}\\
f(1,4)=f(3,4)=8=2^3 \quad f(2,4)=20=2^2*5\\
f(1,5)=f(4,5)=16=2^4 \quad f(2,5)=f(3,5)=80=2^4*5\\
f(1,6)=f(5,6)=2^5 \quad f(2,6)=f(4,6)=2^4*3*7 \quad f(3,6)=2^7*5\\
f(1,7)=f(6,7)=2^6 \quad f(2,7)=f(5,7)=2^6*3*7 \quad f(3,7)=f(4,7)=2^8*3*7\\
f(1,8)=f(7,8)=2^7 \quad f(2,8)=f(6,8)=2^6*5*17 \quad f(3,8)=f(5,8)=2^{11}*3*7 \quad f(4,8)=2^8*3*7*17 \quad \text{etc}\\
$$

Is there any way to calculate $f(m,n)$?

more results
$$
f(1,9)=f(8,9)=2^8 \quad f(2,9)=f(7,9)=2^8*5*17\\
f(3,9)=f(6,9)=2^{12}*5*17 \quad f(4,9)=f(5,9)=2^{12}*3*7*17\\
$$

Comment: Is an action of orthogonal group efficient?

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but I think this OEIS entry agrees with the sequence f(2,1),f(2,2),f(2,3),f(2,4),... and the comments describe how to write down a closed-form formula for f(2,n): http://oeis.org/A320934

Comment: @A.S. Thank you for comments. As I calculated furthermore(results are added), your conjecture seems to be true! But I can't find out the reason for that.

Comment: Thinking of symmetric matrix is effisient...?